# Create copy alert in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-html

Hey am new web developer and am working on a quote website project.

I have created a Html page in which there are some quotes with a copy button below all quotes.

You can visit my CodePen to understand the question clearly
https://codepen.io/Akash11166666/pen/JjRzqzp

(***I have displayed copy buttons and quotes from Javascript so you cannot find the elements in HTML.***)

As you can see my CodePen they work perfectly but we cannot know if the text is copied or not.(In my CodePen I have made the span visible)  So I need a `<span>Copied</span>` to be visible when each copy button is clicked. You cannot find in HTML because,it is ceated from javascript same as copy button was created. They should be so dynamic that, When respective copy button is clicked the`span` element should be visible and invisible after some seconds.

I have tried numerous way to solve this problem but none of them work although am new to javascript and I don't know much about it.

My CodePen project for reference

***My Javascript***

```
    const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button><span class="status-copy-alert">Copied</span></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

  return[{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
]; 
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(

  'click',

  function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {

        const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')

            .childNodes[0].textContent;

        const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

        textArea.value = quote;

        document.body.appendChild(textArea);

        textArea.select();

        document.execCommand('Copy');

        textArea.remove();

    }

  },

  false

);
main();
```

***My Css***

```
/* Main Status */
.mainStatus{
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 max-width: 95%;
 width: 95%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.statusHeading{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #18b495;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.latestatus{
 display: grid;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 width: 445px;
 min-height: 130px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.allStatus{
 display: flex;
}
.latestatus p{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.copystatus{
 font-weight: 500;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
}
.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}
.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #18b495;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 30px;
}
.btn:hover {
 transform: scale(0.98);
}
.status-copy-alert {

 position: relative;

 background-color: #18b495;

 color: #ffffff;

 padding: 10px 10px;

 border-radius: 5px;

 left: 8px;

 text-transform: uppercase;

 letter-spacing: 0.05em;

 font-weight: 500;

 visibility: visible;

}

.status-copy-alert:before{

 content:"";

 position: absolute;

 height: 10px;

 width: 10px;

 background-color: #18b495;

 left: -5px;

 transform: rotate(45deg);

 top: 39%;

}
```

***My Html***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <style>
        /* Main Status */
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <a href="hindinj.html">caeman</a>
      <div class="mainStatus">
        <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
        <div class="allquotes"></div>
        <div class="pagable-status">
          <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
          <div class="pagable-actions">
            <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
            <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
            <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
            <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
            <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
            <select name="page-size">
              <option>20</option>
              <option>10</option>
              <option>20</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
        </div>

        <script>
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

***Again I would tell my problem that, I need a `<span>Copied</span>` to be visible when each copy button is clicked.***

I hartley thanks for those who answer this question.

Comment: [Please only ask each question once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859690/creat-custom-alert-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button><span class="status-copy-alert hidden">Copied</span></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

  return[{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
]; 
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(

  'click',

  function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    

    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {

        const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')

            .childNodes[0].textContent;
      
      const notify = e.target.nextSibling.closest('.status-copy-alert');
      
      notify.classList.toggle('hidden');

        const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

        textArea.value = quote;

        document.body.appendChild(textArea);

        textArea.select();

        document.execCommand('Copy');

        textArea.remove();

    }

  },

  false

);
main();
```

```css
/* Main Status */
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
.mainStatus{
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 max-width: 95%;
 width: 95%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.statusHeading{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #18b495;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.latestatus{
 display: grid;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 width: 445px;
 min-height: 130px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.allStatus{
 display: flex;
}
.latestatus p{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.copystatus{
 font-weight: 500;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
}
.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}
.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #18b495;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 30px;
}
.btn:hover {
 transform: scale(0.98);
}
.status-copy-alert {

 position: relative;

 background-color: #18b495;

 color: #ffffff;

 padding: 10px 10px;

 border-radius: 5px;

 left: 8px;

 text-transform: uppercase;

 letter-spacing: 0.05em;

 font-weight: 500;

 visibility: visible;

}

.status-copy-alert:before{

 content:"";

 position: absolute;

 height: 10px;

 width: 10px;

 background-color: #18b495;

 left: -5px;

 transform: rotate(45deg);

 top: 39%;

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="mainStatus">
   <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
<div class="allquotes"></div>
<div class="pagable-status">
  <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
  <div class="pagable-actions">
    <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
    <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
    <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
    <select name="page-size">
      <option>5</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
</div>
```

I have added a hidden class to the inserted element. On click you can toggle the notification with the hidden class.